# How to fix "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views" in Android Fragment?

Tags: java, android

I have a problem in my code below

```
public class StatusFragment extends Fragment {



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_status, container, false);

        //Untuk menjalankan command dari API
        {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    final TextView tv0 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView0);
                    final TextView tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    final TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                    final TextView tv3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                    final TextView tv4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                    final TextView tv5 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                    final TextView tv6 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
                    final TextView tv7 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
                    final TextView tv8 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView8);

                    ApiConnection con = MainActivity.getCon();
                    if (con !=null)
                        try {

                            //Untuk Menampilkan Resource dari Mikrotik
                            String rs = con.execute("/system/resource/print interval=3",
                                    new ResultListener() {

                                        public void receive(Map<String, String> result) {
                                            tv0.setText(result.get("platform"));
                                            tv1.setText(result.get("board-name"));
                                            tv2.setText(result.get("version"));
                                            tv3.setText(result.get("uptime"));
                                            tv4.setText(String.format("%s %%", result.get("cpu-load")));
                                            tv5.setText(String.format("%s MB", Integer.parseInt(result.get("free-memory")) / (1024*1024)));
                                            tv6.setText(String.format("%s MB", Integer.parseInt(result.get("total-memory")) / (1024*1024)));
                                            tv7.setText(String.format("%s MB", Integer.parseInt(result.get("free-hdd-space")) / (1024*1024)));
                                            tv8.setText(String.format("%s MB", Integer.parseInt(result.get("total-hdd-space")) / (1024*1024)));
                                        }

                                        public void error(MikrotikApiException e) {
                                            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
                                        }

                                        public void completed() {
                                            System.out.println("Asynchronous command has finished");
                                        }
                                    }

                            );


                        } catch (MikrotikApiException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
            });


        }

        return view;
    }

}
```

--------- beginning of crash

> 05-10 08:26:58.797 7122-7164/com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Mikrotik API Result Processor
>       Process: com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2, PID: 7122
>       android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6556)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:907)
>           at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)
>           at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)
>           at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)
>           at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)
>           at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)
>           at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)
>           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:360)
>           at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)
>           at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)
>           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.requestLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:3172)
>           at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)
>           at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)
>           at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)
>           at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:7172)
>           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4342)
>           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4199)
>           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4174)
>           at com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2.StatusFragment$1$1.receive(StatusFragment.java:57)
>           at com.tasanahetech.mikroboxv2.api.impl.ApiConnectionImpl$Processor.run(ApiConnectionImpl.java:258)

Thank you

Comment: The `receive()` method apparently runs on a separate thread. All of the `setText()` calls inside of that are what you want to wrap in the `getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() ...`, not everything in `onCreateView()`.

Comment: You created the view in a fragment and are accessing it's views from outside the fragment.  I think that's what's causing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way to resolve the problem is, wrap all "tv0.setText()" call inside receive() function to another "runOnUiThread" block. Like this:

```
public void receive(Map<String, String> result) {
  getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      tv0.setText(result.get("platform"));
      tv1.setText(result.get("board-name"));
      tv2.setText(result.get("version"));
      tv3.setText(result.get("uptime"));
      tv4.setText(String.format("%s %%", result.get("cpu-load")));
      tv5.setText(String.format("%s MB", Integer.parseInt(result.get("free-memory")) / (1024*1024)));
      tv6.setText(String.format("%s MB", Integer.parseInt(result.get("total-memory")) / (1024*1024)));
      tv7.setText(String.format("%s MB", Integer.parseInt(result.get("free-hdd-space")) / (1024*1024)));
      tv8.setText(String.format("%s MB", Integer.parseInt(result.get("total-hdd-space")) / (1024*1024)));
  });
}
```

and the outter "getActivity().runOnUiThread" can be removed.